# Maya Python script applies texture to all objects instead of selected object

Tags: python, maya, mel

I'm using a script given by Adobe's substance painter that is supposed to import a sbsar file and turn it into a shader node and then apply it to the object selected, but when I execute the script it applies it to all objects in the scene.

```py
import maya.cmds as cmds 
 
def _connect_place2d(substance_node): 
    """ Connects the place2d texture node to the Substance node """ 
    place_node = cmds.shadingNode('place2dTexture', asUtility=True) 
 
    connect_attrs = [('outUV', 'uvCoord'), ('outUvFilterSize', 'uvFilterSize')] 
 
    for out_attr, in_attr in connect_attrs: 
        cmds.connectAttr('{}.{}'.format(place_node, out_attr), 
                         '{}.{}'.format(substance_node, in_attr)) 
 
def _find_shading_group(node): 
    """ Walks the shader graph to find the shading group """ 
    result = None 
 
    connections = cmds.listConnections(node, source=False) 
 
    if connections: 
        for connection in connections: 
            if cmds.nodeType(connection) == 'shadingEngine': 
                result = connection 
            else: 
                result = _find_shading_group(connection) 
                if result is not None: 
                    break 
 
    return result 
 
def _apply_substance_workflow_to_selected(substance_file, workflow): 
    """ Imports a mesh into Maya and applies the shader from a 
        Substance workflow to it """ 
    geometry = cmds.ls(geometry=True) 
 
    # Create the substance node and connect the place2d texture node 
    substance_node = cmds.shadingNode('substanceNode', asTexture=True) 
    _connect_place2d(substance_node) 
 
    # Load the Substance file 
    cmds.substanceNodeLoadSubstance(substance_node, substance_file) 
 
    # Apply the workflow 
    cmds.substanceNodeApplyWorkflow(substance_node, workflow=workflow) 
 
    # Acquire the shading group and apply it to the mesh 
    shading_group = _find_shading_group(substance_node) 
 
 
def demo_load_sbsar_workflow(): 
    """ Acquires an sbsar from a file dialog, loading and applying it to 
        any selected mesh """ 
    file_filter = 'Substance (*.sbsar);;' 
 
    files = cmds.fileDialog2(cap='Select a Substance file', fm=1, dialogStyle=2, 
                             okc='Open', fileFilter=file_filter) 
 
    if files: 
        substance_file = files[0] 
        _apply_substance_workflow_to_selected(substance_file, 
                                              cmds.substanceGetWorkflow()) 
 
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    demo_load_sbsar_workflow()
```

I was fully expecting it to apply the selected texture immediately to the mesh I had selected and not every object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `geometry = cmds.ls(geometry=True)` simply selects all geometies, if you exchange it with:

geometry = cmds.ls(sl=True, geometry=True)

it only chooses the selected shapes, but you have to select the shape nodes.

Comment: This managed to work but is there a way to get it so I only need to select the mesh and not open the node editor?

Comment: If your transform only have one shape you can try this: `geometry = [cmds.listRelatives(x, s=True)[0] for x in cmds.ls(sl=True)]`. But it only uses the first shape node under every selected transform.

Comment: that one did nothing sadly.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply it ended up working with edit you gave me just need to make sure nothing in my scene has history.